# FileInfo Array From Strings

Tags: c#, arrays, fileinfo

Currently I am getting the size of a file by using:

```
FileInfo fileSize = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");
long size = fileSize.Length;
```

Rather than do this for every file I want, I thought you must be able to use an array and iterate through them so I used this:

```
FileInfo[] fileSizes = new FileInfo[2];
fileSizes[0] = @"C:\file.txt";
fileSizes[1] = @"C:\file.txt";
```

Now I keep getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IO.FileInfo'". I tried using .ToString() but no dice, any help is very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: fileSizes[0] = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt"); you need more coffee :D and fileSizes[2] is out of range

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I never twigged on that, yeah I do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't store multiple files in a `FileInfo` array. To fix your error, you need to do this:

```
FileInfo[] fileSizes = new FileInfo[3];
fileSizes[0] = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");
fileSizes[1] = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");
fileSizes[2] = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");
```

However, you should store them like this (below) and iterate through the list and load one `FileInfo` at a time:

```
String[] files = new String[3];
files[0] = @"C:\file.txt";
files[1] = @"C:\file.txt";
files[2] = @"C:\file.txt";

foreach (String file in files)
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
    // do something with info.Length
}
```

Comment: Off by one error? `FileInfo[] fileSizes = new FileInfo[2];` should be `FileInfo[] fileSizes = new FileInfo[3];`

Comment: Thats my mistake, I put it out of range by accident, he was just copying my code +1

Comment: Looping was exactly what I was planning on doing, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
FileInfo[] fileSizes = new FileInfo[3];
fileSizes[0] = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");
fileSizes[1] = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");
fileSizes[2] = new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");
```

@"C:\file.txt" is a string, not the object itself..

Answer (score 1):

replace `@"C:\file.txt";` with `new FileInfo(@"C:\file.txt");`